# Query XML by node value

Tags: c#, xml

I'm querying the following xml:

https://snipt.net/api/public/snipt/?q=Leadwerks&format=xml

I first list all code snippet titles by looping over all the titles like:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlSnippets.SelectNodes("//response/objects/object/title");
```

I place them in a `listbox`. When I click on a title in the `listbox` I want to then query the loaded `xml` file again for the title inner text and get it's parent node so I can then get the code node to show in a `textbox`.

How do I query an xml file for some inner text of node and then get that nodes parent?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: That's not how we do things here. You need to do your research first. When you try something and have a problem, come back and ask. Here's a hint: that thing in quotes in the `SelectNodes` is called "XPATH".

Comment: Also if you are not forced to use what you are using now, look into XDocument. Much easier than using XPath IMO.

Comment: Thanks Francis, I'll check out XDocument. John, I googled but wasn't coming up with anything. So thought I'd reach out to see if anyone could help point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out

```
"//response/objects/object/title[text()='" + value + "']"
```

Looks like doing [text()=''] is how you would query for values.